# Failed review audit for a question marked as possible spam, but appears genuine

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I reviewed this question [Quartz.net - Simulating the Passing of Time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7896647) and got a ban as it was marked as spam, but it seems a genuine attempt at a question. I admit, not particularly well formatted, and possibly a "Needs Improvement" response might also have been a valid response, but I think it is fairly clear what is being asked anyway.

I entered the question title into the "New question" workflow and it didn't come up with any obvious duplicates.

General observation (which I see has already been raised) that it would be convenient to be able to dispute these audits (perhaps at the cost of rep points if the audit was plainly correct).

The link works for me, but for those who can't view it, the question was:

> I've found Quartz.net a very useful way of handling scheduling but for
>   testing and a few other reasons I want to be capable of simulating
>   time rather than using the system time of my computer. For this from
>   what I can find, I believe I will need to modify the SystemTime and I
>   have found a few examples on how to do this from other people's
>   answered questions. But one thing I'd want to be able to do is speed
>   up, slow down, or pause passing of time. I know that I can switch and
>   pause triggers but that isn't what I want and doesn't really meet my
>   purposes. While I could change out a trigger that is set to occur for
>   every hour to occur instead every minute it wouldn't really be meeting
>   my requirement of simulating normal run time and switching out several
>   triggers seems more likely to cause errors to occur. Also pausing
>   triggers doesn't work because time itself would still be passing and
>   thus when I start them again it wouldn't act as if the clock itself
>   had been paused. I apologize if this has already been answered but I
>   haven't been able to find an example or of it or good documentation on
>   SystemTime (or TimeSpanParseRuleAttribute if that is what I should be
>   using).
>
> deleted by Bill the Lizard♦ Apr 17 at 14:03

Tags all seemed correct.

Comment: The question no longer exists so it's hard for us to discuss if you where right or not.

Comment: @BramDriesen , moderators and other users with high reputation ( I don't remember exactly how much ) can view deleted question, so it's not completely useless.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily spam, but it is a very bad question. "Looks OK" is *certainly* the wrong choice. @ArunA.S Seeing deleted posts is at 10k rep. :)

Comment: Personally, I find the question unclear so even if it's not intended as a spam, it is certainly not qualified as a "looks ok" question. That's my 2 cents to the discussion.

Comment: I am not going to get too upset over this one - it's only a review audit and maybe I should have marked it for improvement, but my thoughts were that the problems were mainly with formatting (i.e., lack of paragraphs) than anything else - the actual question makes sense and shows some research - certainly compared with the general quality of stuff on this site. But it is not the first time, and I just wanted to add my weight to the other requests that maybe some improvements could be done in this area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spam flag wasn't warranted, so deleting that question as spam was a mistake. I cleared the flag so it won't show up in /review again, and undeleted the question. It is rather low-quality, though, so I've just closed the question.

Comment: Yes - fair enough.